# "Error: Unable to create database user: Database user name is invalid." when trying to restore SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore

I backed up a database and then did some necessary modification in the same offline, after all work is done, I am trying to restore it back onto my website. I am using Parallels Plesk control panel.

Now I get this error:

> Error: Unable to creste database user: Database user name is invalid. Only latin letters are allowed in the database user name

Comment: I am unable to install SSMS on server. Its "windows Server 2008 R2 Standard".

Comment: Simple Search yielded this many results  [link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Database+user+name+is+invalid.+Only+latin+letters+are+allowed+in+the+database+user+name&oq=Database+user+name+is+invalid.+Only+latin+letters+are+allowed+in+the+database+user+name&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8),try them

Comment: I tried nothing worked.

Comment: So when you tried this: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/problem-with-restore-ms-sql-server-2008-database.274446/#post-701945, did you get an identical error? How many of those Google results did you try and did you get the same error everytime?